# Update columns of a table which data contains from another table mysql

Tags: mysql

I am about to update records which contain data from another table. From the given example table data below, I want to update the `NULL` values of `company_name` and `domain` of log table:

**User Table**

```
id | email_address
1    test@gmail.com
2    test@yahoo.com
```

**Log table**

```
id | user_id | company_name | domain
 1     1       NULL         | NULL
 2     1       NULL         | NULL
 3     2       Yahoo        | yahoo.com
 4     1       Google Inc   | gmail.com
```

**Company_domain table**

```
id | company    | domain      
1  | Google Inc | google.com,gmail.com,gmail.com.us
2  | Yahoo      | yahoo.com,yahoomail.com
```

The `company_name` should be based on the domain of user email address. From the example log table above, the company_name of id #3 is Yahoo since the `user_id=2` which is test@yahoo.com. This should also reflect on `log.domain`

My sql query below does not match with the company.

```
UPDATE user_log AS log INNER JOIN user AS u ON u.id=log.user_id
SET log.domain = (
   select (SUBSTR(u.email_address, INSTR(u.email_address, '@') + 1))
),
log.company_name = (
   SELECT company FROM company_domain
   WHERE find_in_set(
    (
        SELECT (SUBSTR(log.domain, INSTR(log.domain, '@') + 1))
    ),
    domain
 )
);
```

Does anybody know?

Comment: It would be great if the table names in the question matched and were consistent with the table names in the published query.

Comment: Also, is the `domains` column really storing a comma separated list of values? That's usually a bad design... Databases are designed to work best with rows of information, not csv strings.

Comment: *From the given example table data below* Provide this as online fiddle or as CREATE TABLE +INSERT INTO. Provide desired output for shown sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I got this sql query working on my local. I notice that the domain should come from the email address since the domain from log table is null.

```
UPDATE user_log ul 
INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = ul.user_id
SET
 ul.domain = (
   SELECT (SUBSTR(u.email_address, INSTR(u.email_address, '@') + 1))
 ),
 ul.company_name = (
     SELECT company FROM company_domain
     WHERE FIND_IN_SET(
      (
        SELECT (SUBSTR(u.email_address, INSTR(u.email_address, '@') + 1))
      ),
      domain
    ) LIMIT 1
 );
```